# How can I get an int from a database using clr/c++ and convert it into a system::int

Tags: sql, c++-cli

The problem that I am having is that I want to read an integer value from a database but I need to do CLR conversions to do this as it needs to be appended onto another integer from my database and then written back into the database. I have already done string conversions in this project so I do not see why I cannot do integer.

Code I already have:

```
try
        {
            OleDbDataReader^ reader = testData.openData(fieldEntity, field, tableName);
            while (reader->Read())
            {
                string userName, passWord;
                String^ username = reader["username"]->ToString();
                String^ password = reader["password"]->ToString();
                stringConversion(username, userName);
                stringConversion(password, passWord);
                /* this means that i will have the System::String^ as system::string and I want the same as this but for integers not strings*/
            }
         }
```

stringConversion

```
void stringConversion(String ^ s, string& os)
{
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const char* chars =
        (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}
```

Edit: my catch statement is missing but it doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem and it is actually rather basic.

When dealing with an object I can just cast it in the same way I would a normal variable.

For example,

```
    OleDbDataReader^ reader = testData.openData(fieldEntity, field, tableName);
        while (reader ->Read())
        {
            Object^ healthptr = reader["Health"];
            health = (int)healthptr;
        }
```